# If a policy has not been updated by the time that was specified in a policy, does it still apply?

Tags: australia

Ok so I have a policy that states that it should have been updated in December 2019, but hasn't. Does it still apply?

The exact wording of the relevant section is:

> REVIEW PERIOD:
> This policy was last updated on Tuesday 4th December and is scheduled for review in December
> 2019.

Please note that I do not have any background in law, so excuse me if I asked a question with an obvious answer.

Comment: What type of policy?  Also, it says "scheduled for review" - does anything say it's cancelled if not reviewed, or describe extension procedures?

Comment: Please don't use codeblock for anything that is not actual code. Quoteblock should be used for direct quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a policy has not been updated by the time that was specified in a policy, does it still apply?

Most likely it does. The only information you provide favors the interpretation that the policy would still apply, since "*review*" and "*expiration*" are two different concepts.

The only conclusion that can be reached with certainty is that the parties cannot reasonably expect any changes to the policy to occur prior to December 2019.

Had the clause being drafted in terms of "*renew*" instead of "*review*", there would be more merit to the interpretation "*the policy will no longer apply upon December 2019 unless steps x, y, and z are taken*".